# How do I use BertForMaskedLM or BertModel to calculate perplexity of a sentence?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, transformer-model, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I want to use BertForMaskedLM or BertModel to calculate perplexity of a sentence, so I write code like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM
# Load pre-trained model (weights)
with torch.no_grad():
    model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('hfl/chinese-bert-wwm-ext')
    model.eval()
    # Load pre-trained model tokenizer (vocabulary)
    tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('hfl/chinese-bert-wwm-ext')
    sentence = "我不会忘记和你一起奋斗的时光。"
    tokenize_input = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
    tensor_input = torch.tensor([tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenize_input)])
    sen_len = len(tokenize_input)
    sentence_loss = 0.

    for i, word in enumerate(tokenize_input):
        # add mask to i-th character of the sentence
        tokenize_input[i] = '[MASK]'
        mask_input = torch.tensor([tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenize_input)])

        output = model(mask_input)

        prediction_scores = output[0]
        softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=0)
        ps = softmax(prediction_scores[0, i]).log()
        word_loss = ps[tensor_input[0, i]]
        sentence_loss += word_loss.item()

        tokenize_input[i] = word
    ppl = np.exp(-sentence_loss/sen_len)
    print(ppl)
```

I think this code is right, but I also notice BertForMaskedLM's paramaters `masked_lm_labels`, so could I use this paramaters to calculate PPL of a sentence easiler?
I know the input_ids argument is the masked input, the masked_lm_labels argument is the desired output. But I couldn't understand the actual meaning of its output loss, its code like this:

```
if masked_lm_labels is not None:
    loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()  # -100 index = padding token
    masked_lm_loss = loss_fct(prediction_scores.view(-1, self.config.vocab_size), 
    masked_lm_labels.view(-1))
    outputs = (masked_lm_loss,) + outputs
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use the  parameter `labels` (or `masked_lm_labels`, I think the param name varies in versions of huggingface transformers, whatever) to specify the masked token position, and use `-100` to ignore the tokens that you dont want to include in the loss computing.
For example,

```py
sentence='我爱你'
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM
import torch
import numpy as np

tokenizer = BertTokenizer(vocab_file='vocab.txt')
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-chinese')

tensor_input = tokenizer(sentence, return_tensors='pt')
# tensor([[ 101, 2769, 4263,  872,  102]])

repeat_input = tensor_input.repeat(tensor_input.size(-1)-2, 1)
# tensor([[ 101, 2769, 4263,  872,  102],
#         [ 101, 2769, 4263,  872,  102],
#         [ 101, 2769, 4263,  872,  102]])

mask = torch.ones(tensor_input.size(-1) - 1).diag(1)[:-2]
# tensor([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])

masked_input = repeat_input.masked_fill(mask == 1, 103)
# tensor([[ 101,  103, 4263,  872,  102],
#         [ 101, 2769,  103,  872,  102],
#         [ 101, 2769, 4263,  103,  102]])

labels = repeat_input.masked_fill( masked_input != 103, -100)
# tensor([[-100, 2769, -100, -100, -100],
#         [-100, -100, 4263, -100, -100],
#         [-100, -100, -100,  872, -100]])

loss,_ = model(masked_input, masked_lm_labels=labels)

score = np.exp(loss.item())
```

The function:

```py
def score(model, tokenizer, sentence,  mask_token_id=103):
  tensor_input = tokenizer.encode(sentence, return_tensors='pt')
  repeat_input = tensor_input.repeat(tensor_input.size(-1)-2, 1)
  mask = torch.ones(tensor_input.size(-1) - 1).diag(1)[:-2]
  masked_input = repeat_input.masked_fill(mask == 1, 103)
  labels = repeat_input.masked_fill( masked_input != 103, -100)
  loss,_ = model(masked_input, masked_lm_labels=labels)
  result = np.exp(loss.item())
  return result

score(model, tokenizer, '我爱你') # returns 45.63794545581973
```

Comment: Hi Emily, shouldn't you use `BertModel`, as the OP wants the perplexity of the sentence, and not the perplexity of the masked tokens?

Comment: Hi, @AshwinGeetD'Sa , we get the perplexity of the sentence by masking one token at a time and averaging the loss of all steps. The OP do it by a for-loop. I just put the input of each step together as a batch, and feed it to the Model.

Comment: Thank you. I get it and I need more 'tensor' awareness, hh.

Comment: And I also want to know how how to calculate the PPL of sentences in batches. Would you like to give me some advice? I'd be happy if you could give me some advice.

Comment: This approach incorrect from math point of view. p(x) = p(x[0]) p(x[1]|x[0]) p(x[2]|x[:2]) ... p(x[n]|x[:n]) . But you are doing p(x)=p(x[0]|x[1:]) p(x[1]|x[0]x[2:]) p(x[2]|x[:2] x[3:])...p(x[n]|x[:n]) . There is actually no definition of perplexity for BERT. We would have to use causal model with attention mask. Masked language models don't have perplexity. https://www.reddit.com/r/LanguageTechnology/comments/eh4lt9/bert_sentence_perplexity/